# In 14.04, how do I persist a view in Nautilus-Gnome?

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, gnome-classic

I just upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04 and I use the Gnome (MetaCity) UI. I set up a view in Nautilus like this, **including the side bar and location entry box.**

[image]

I want to persist this view so that whenever I open Nautilus it will look like this. But each time I close and re-open Nautilus it reverts to my default view:

[image]

The settings that are available in Location Options-> Preferences persist but those set in other menus, such as View Options->Show Sidebar do not.

How can I set things up so that Nautilus always opens with my preferred view (first screen shot). I think this worked in 12.04, but perhaps not?